# Can I connect to websocket via devtool?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Can I connect the existing WebSocket via chrome devtool? I see ws connection and messages, but It wrapped by react and handle all logic of connection(token and other data). I haven't access to the source code, but I want to try to send messages to the existing socket. Can I do it with any tools?

Comment: You can download chrome extension, e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo

Comment: it will create new connection, but I need to send messages to already existing connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you are familiar wuth teh network panel of the chrom dev tool. However, in the browser select your site , here it is, https://www.ls-x.de/de/, for stock data, open the dev tools and in there open the network panel. Make a refresh, CTRL-R, of the website and you will see something similar like in the picture below.

[image]

In the column **Initiator**  you see the source file from which the websocket was opened. Click on that entry. This will open the Sources tab in dev tools where you will see the line where the websocket is created.

[image]

Set a break point there and again do a refresh, CTRL-R, of the web page. This will cause the debugger to stop right at this line. From here you have to single step through the code until you see the vaiable where the web socket will be stored.
You can also search in this source for something like **.send(** . that probably indicates the send function of the websocket.

If you find this send function, place a breakpoint at that line and do a refresh again. The debugger will lead you right to that point where you can send a message. now.

Comment: Thanks, it can help me. I can change code via devtool and save socket to global variable.